# How do I get Old value to checkbox in Laravel using a JSON column?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my project, I am using MySQL 5.7 with a JSON column that has the following structure inside:

```
[{"name": "Students"}, {"name": "Teachers"}]
```

I need to keep that format of objects in the array for searching later on, however, when I try to create an edit form using checkboxes, I cant get them to select the ones that are already in the array.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('audiences[][name]', 'Students', in_array('Students', $audiences)) !!} Students</label><br/>
<label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('audiences[][name]', 'Teachers', in_array('Teachers', $audiences)) !!} Teachers</label><br/>
```

Any advice on how I can do this?

Comment: Did you try `checkbox('audiences[name][]')`? I'm assuming that you have a column `audiences` in your database.

Comment: There is a JSON column name called audiences yes. Audiences has a whole bunch of objects with name as a value inside it. Unfortunately audiences[name][] just assumes it is one object with an array of names.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, I still can't figure out for sure what you are trying to do.